# Use subclass member variable in super class methods?

Tags: java

I have a base class and subclass. Base class has common methods and its implementation which I want to use in subclass but I want to use subclass member variable instead of superclass. I do not want to rewrite the same method in subclass. Is there a way in Java to achieve this.

Comment: You cannot override fields, but you can override getter methods, and so one possible solution I think is to use *getter* methods to get the fields.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what you want to achieve? I could imagine that an abstract class is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method to access the member and override it in subclasses.

```
Class A{
  public void DoStuff(){
     int aux = getResource; 
     /*cool things with aux*/
  }
  protected int getResource(){
    return internal_member;
  }
  private int internal_member;
}

Class B extends A{
  private int another_member;
  @Override
  public int getResource(){
     return another_member;
  }

}
```

But take into account that this will not prevent people chaging class A from using the member directly, It might be better to create a base class for the members and the getters.

Another Option, as some people outlined before is to have the data member in the base class as protected and initialize it in the subclass:

```
Class A{
  public void DoStuff(){
     /*cool things with internal_member*/
  }
  protected List internal_member;
  A(){internal_member = /*Set here a value*/}
}

Class B extends A{
  B(){internal_member = /*Set a different value here! you can even declare a member and assign it here*/}

}
```

You can use constructors with arguments if you need.

Comment: That is strange looking Java code. It looks almost like C++ to me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks! I was the whole day with C++ and when I wrote the answer I did it fast and did not realize! lol

Comment: I have something like this :  public class Base{ 
List A ; 
base(){
this.A = A
}  
public doSomethingOnList () {
} 
}

public child extends Base{
@override
List B;
child(){
super();
this.B = B
 }
}

I want doSomethingOnList() method defined in base class to use Child class List B instead of List A. I do not want to write same method in child class. Does inheritence take care of that or I have to write setters ?

Comment: It is not possible to override directly a data member sorry, that wont work. You need to declare a getter and override it. Also, you can set the value from the constructor. I am editing the code to show what I mean.

Comment: Thanks.. I created a setter and called it in subclass constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `protected` setter on the member variable & then override the value of the super's variable within the constructor of the subclass:

```
class Animal {
   private String voice = "Oooo";

   protected void setVoice(String voice) {
       this.voice = voice;
   }

   public void speak() {
       System.out.println(this.voice);
   }

}

class Dog extends Animal {

    public Dog() {
        setVoice("woof"); 
    }

}
```